# Vue and Typescript 3.5.3 complaining about `ComputedOptions<any>`

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a working Vue application written in Typescript. Yesterday I have update Typescript from 3.1.5 to 3.5.3, and the application no longer compiles, yielding around 200 errors. I have tried to recreate these issues in a small sample application, but everything I've tried there does work.

The first error in every file is always similar to this:

`Property ... does not exist on type ComputedOptions<any> | (()=>any)`

For example, the following computer property:

```js
   props: {
       params: EditorParams,
   },

   computed: {
      zoom(): number {
          return this.params.zoom;
      },
   }
```

Yields the error `Property 'params' does not exist on type ComputedOptions<any> | (()=>any)`

This error then causes a cascade of other errors. It is as if Typescript does not find the proper type information of many many properties, data elements and computed properties. All the types are defined properly (with Typescript 3.1.5 everything just works).

I'm really lost here. The application is quite large. These errors occur in 9 files out of a few dozens. All these files are vue components, but there are more components that work well.

Comment: It would be far easier to help you if you could reduce your problem down to a replicatable sample. Either remove bits from your existing project until it's small enough or add bits to a sample project until it encounters the same problem.

Comment: Of course it would, but I wasn't able. Reducing the project to a minimal set is not feasible - too many interconntected pieces. I tried to reproduce this in a sample, but I couldn't - everything just works. I was hoping the error message itself can provide a hint to someone.

Comment: What is the TypeScript definition of parent type for that snippet? And definition for `computed`?

Comment: `computed` is the Vue's computed properties. `ComputedOptions<T>` is a Vue type, not mine. `EditorParams` is just an interface with some properties - the same error occurs when the property has other types, including `any`